# mmenu with position front and sliding submenu: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I'm trying to use mmenu for the first time in a new project. How can I get two functions working: sliding submenu: false and position front, left? I'm a newbie in Javascript and JQuery. I tried some ways to combine the two functions as well as use both. Only the first placed function works.
Hope someone can give me a hint. Thanks!

The scripts I want working both combined:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#navMain").mmenu({
            slidingSubmenus: false
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#navMain").mmenu({
            offCanvas: {
                position: "right",
                zposition: "front"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here the Link to my project.](http://brueckmann-design.de/Test/siehste/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#navMain").mmenu({
            slidingSubmenus: false,
offCanvas: {
                position: "right",
                zposition: "front"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please can you add some explanation - why this will work and the OP's code was wrong? This would then be a better answer.